# Pause all other players besides activated one. jQuery audio plugin for <audio> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this plugin which applies different style to html5 `<audio>` element and provides flash fallback to browsers that don't support .mp3 file format. Problem I encountered is that once you start playing one song, and then click play on any other song, all of them will play at the same time, which is bad user experience.

I was trying to figure out how to edit plugin to make it only play one song at a time, so say if user listens to one song and then click play on other, first one should pause, and so on.
I'm not entirely sure, but I think something need's to be edited along these lines:

```
    playPause: function() {
      if (this.playing) this.pause();
      else this.play();
    },
```

However, there are various places in the plugin which seem to deal with playing and pausing song, so I'm not sure that this is exact correct line for this. I'm still very new to jQuery, and can't entirely figure out how this big audio library works, I've been reading through code comment's , but still am unable to figure this out.

Full code of the plugin is available here: http://freshbeer.lv/mg/js/audio.min.js 
 Official plugin website: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ 
You can visit my demo page to see the issue, just click play on several players and you will see that they all play at the same time: http://freshbeer.lv/mg/index.html

Comment: Does the plugin use the html5 <audio> element?  If so you can do something like audioTrack.pause() in javascript or omit the autoplay attribute for the element.

Comment: @TwistedInferno indeed it does, not sure what you mean by auto play attribute, as at the moment it is not used anywhere. Issue is that once user plays one song and than clicks play on other players, they all play at the same time, so several songs. Could you expand on audioTrack.pause()? How can I use it in order to pause previous players, but make current one still play the song?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the addEventListener and the play event.  This pauses all players except the one that the play button has been pressed on.

```
        audiojs.events.ready(function () {
            var as = audiojs.createAll();

            $('audio').each(function () {
                var myAudio = this;
                this.addEventListener('play', function () {
                    $('audio').each(function () {
                        if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                            this.pause();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: what? did you get this audio element from my page? The one I have there is like this (I'm confused, what browser are you testing it in?): <audio preload="none" src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/75868018/stream?client_id=7a17129ba9cd5fff34f847e3539829b7"></audio>

Comment: you say it uses a html5 element, that's what a html5 audio element looks like.  I can't access your page due to an unauthorized access error.  (thanks for trying anyway?)

Comment: try the js if you can't access the autoplay attribute

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to sound rude, I was just confused, because your audio element looks very different, but yea my one hasn't got autopay attribute, and I think second method "audioTrack.pause();" would just pause all players, even one that user clicked on play, correct? I do appreciate your time, thank you. Also how come you can't access demo website? I tired it out, it seems to work, what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry, I think I misunderstood your problem!  Add an id to each of your audio elements then attach a play event handler to each of those that pauses all the other players.

Comment: var audioTrack1 = document.getElementById('audioTrack1');
audioTrack1.play = function(){ audioTrack2.pause(); }

Comment: each audio element is within a wrapper div, such divs have id's like audiojs_wrapper0, audiojs_wrapper1 etc.. I can use this to target specific audio element within them. The bit I don't understand is how to pause all other players except one that user clicked. Each wrapper also has a class="audiojs" can we somehow pause all players inside .audiojs except player thats inside (lets asume) #audiojs_wrapper1 ?

Comment: use this selector if just the div has an id  $('#audiojs_wrapper1 audio')[0].pause();

Comment: I guess it should work, the problem is that I don't have fixed amount of players on a page, as they are part of posts that are taken from database. Therefore I don't think I can apply this solution. I edited my question, hopefully it makes more sense. But I assume it's hard to understand my issue if you can't access demo site and jQuery plugin code.

Comment: how about this, might be my last attempt!

Comment: Tried modifying it to meet plugin needs, but still nothing. I'm really sorry to have up so much of you'r time, I'm new to jQuery and perhaps your answer contains a fix, it could be just me who is bad with applying it, here is what I came up with, but it didn't work: $('.audiojs').each(function () {
var playedPlayer = this;var player = this.settings.createPlayer;$('audiojs').each(function () {
if (!(this === playedPlayer)) {container[audiojs].helpers.removeClass(this.wrapper,player.playingClass);
} else {container[audiojs].helpers.addClass(this.wrapper,player.playingClass); } }); });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28312/discussion-between-twisted-inferno-and-ilya)