# I have multiple HTML 5 <Audio> tags on one page and I want ALL of them to pause when another is played

Tags: html, audio, controls, pause

I think I need a script that will "get" all the playing HTML5 audio controls and "pause" them apart from the one the user clicks play on. I have seen and can handle simple play, pause, stop with just one audio controls but my skills fall way short of coding something to do what I'm after with multiples. audio controls is a neat solution and integrates well with my current design, I just need help making it work properly. The use case:

https://aberaeronskies.com/ page loads and nothing plays which is desired, user clicks play on a audio controls tag and the track snippet plays which is desired. User clicks on another one (there are 14) and it starts to play, trouble is, the first one is still playing which is not desired; one could click on all of them and they would all play!

The requirement is for a script or a call or whatever (I'm no coder, just doing this as freebie for a mate) that when a user clicks play on any one of the 14 tracks it pauses all other playing tracks.

I thought this was it: [Pause all other players besides activated one. jQuery audio plugin for <audio> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015334/pause-all-other-players-besides-activated-one-jquery-audio-plugin-for-audio-e) and [Play selected audio while pausing/resetting others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689920/play-selected-audio-while-pausing-resetting-others) but I'cant make them work.

It may be that this cannot be done and I need to rethink the whole presentation of multiple tracks and if so, further advice on where to look (in addition to above) would also be useful.

Thanks very much...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that this forum is for helping answer code related problems and require a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see what code you have tried and where you are experiencing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah...
This works

```
var curPlaying;
window.addEventListener("play", function(evt)
{
if(window.$_currentlyPlaying && window.$_currentlyPlaying != evt.target)
{
    window.$_currentlyPlaying.pause();
} 
window.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target;
}, true);
$(function () {
$(".playback").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
    if (song.paused) {
        if (curPlaying) {
            $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();
        }
        song.play();
        curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    } else {
        song.pause();
        curPlaying = null;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5057453/amin-baig (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877828/multiple-html5-audio-players-play-control) for eventual solution.